# Accidentally modified IOS CoreLocation header file, It can't compile

Tags: ios, frameworks

It seem that I had modified the CLLocationManager header file. What should I do to fix it, help me, thanks a lot.[image]

[image]

Comment: how did u modified the CLLocationManager header file? because it is a locked one

Comment: Could we get you to post the rest of the file above this part, removing comments to save space?

Comment: I posted the rest of the file above this part

Comment: you should try because sometimes it's show error. developers forgot to give more spaces between line it was happened.

Answer (score 0):

change line to ordered single line

```
-(void)allowDeferredLocationUpdatesunitTraveled:(CLLocationDistance)distance timeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout _OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_MAC_NA,__IPHONE_6_0);
```

Comment: why not remove the space between the lines

Comment: I have try, but it still have the same error, i have no idea how to fix it, can I remove iOS 7 SDK and reinstall it?

Comment: No, it's small bug don't waste your time

Comment: I fixed it, t's really a strange thing, i deleted it builded success, and the then i pasted the method and builded again, it also builded success.

Comment: Multiple line declarations are legal in Objective-C. The problem is likely to have been caused by the addition of an invisible character somewhere.